# How to search excel for multiple words, in multiple cells, with Yes or No output?

Tags: excel-formula

Here are my two working formulas, I want to merge into one please suggest

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"String 1"},E2))),"YES", "NO")
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"String 2"},E3))),"YES", "NO")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question because it is **ambiguous**.

If you mean you want **both** tests to be true to yield a *Yes*, you would use *AND()*; if you mean you want **either** test to pass, you would use *OR()*:

Here is the formula for the *OR()* case:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"String 1"},E2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"String 2"},E3))),"YES", "NO")
```

and here is the *AND()* case:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"String 1"},E2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"String 2"},E3))),"YES", "NO")
```

Comment: Perfect.  My apologies about the ambiguous, so I greatly appreciate both examples as that gave me MORE information, AND taught me the differences on AND and OR options for future use.  I originally had a similar solution but I just could not figure out the placements of the IF and OR and where the (parenthesis) and where the "Yes", "No" should be placed.  You examples showed me all of that in one simple answer.  I am hoping this answer will be useful for others in the future (as I could not find a 'clear' example (that was not a 'math' example).  Thanks.